# wooCommerce wirecard plugin giving issues

Tags: woocommerce

When after selecting wired card as a payment option in the checkout page, 
instead of redirecting to the wiredcard checkout page. I get an incomplete form error saying please select a payment type.

Any idea what's wrong?

on the wirecard checcout settings i have selected two types of payments . i.e credit card and maestro

Also one more thing when I used the iDeal Payment option it will give me the error: payment type is not activated.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the secret key and customer id number in backend side.